# How to Parse date time String to DateTime using Apex

Tags: apex, datetime

Given this string value:

```
String dateTimeString = '20/12/18 16:39:51'; // or '31/10/18 09:35:16'
```

How would I parse it to a `DateTime`?

I've tried this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
```

But I get this error:

> System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 20/12/18 16:39:51

I've tried this:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) JSON.deserialize('"' + dateTimeString + '"', DateTime.class);
```

But I get this error:

> System.JSONException: Invalid format: "20/12/18 16:39:51" is malformed
>   at "/12/18 16:39:51"

Comment: Where are you getting this string from? Are you not able to at least get four digit years?

Comment: @AdrianLarson It's coming from an external API / System

Comment: Do you know if you'll get leading zeroes on the time elements?

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes the hour will have a leading zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on sfdcfox's answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235806/parse-date-time-string-to-apex-datetime)

```
Pattern dt = Pattern.compile('(?i)(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})');
String exampleTime = '20/12/18 16:39:51';
Matcher m = dt.matcher(exampletime);
DateTime result;
if(m.find()) {
    result = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(
        Integer.valueOf('20' + m.group(3)), // yuck
        Integer.valueOf(m.group(2)),
        Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)),
        Integer.valueOf(m.group(4)),
        Integer.valueOf(m.group(5)),
        Integer.valueOf(m.group(6))        
        );
}
System.debug(result);
```

Note where I pre-pend `20` to the first parameter of the `newInstanceGMT` method